How to get the initial ID for keyset pagnination?
I am new to keyset pagination and have a question.
I saw this query:
SELECT * 
FROM event 
WHERE 
 id < @UUID AND created_at < @Date
ORDER BY 
  id ASC,
  created_at ASC,
LIMIT 3;

Where does the UUID for the first query come from?
For the first request I can't send an ID while I don't have any data. For a second request I can check the ID from the previous call. But where to get my UUID for the first query?

Just select the first one: SELECT MIN(id) FROM event WHERE created_at < @date;

@FrankHeikens hi thanks, if I only want to select first user or last user can I just use the created_at parameter even for second or third queries ? So then I dont need do filter WHERE id then I just can use WHERE created_at ... is that right ?

Assuming id is unique then you probably have the columns in teh wrong order: created_at should be first.

For the first iteration, just omit the WHERE clause completely.
After that, you have values to fill in to your WHERE clause from the previous iteration.
For the record: the query you display is typically wrong for keyset pagination.
You should use ROW value comparison instead.
And the < operator does not match your sort order ASC.
This would work:
SELECT * 
FROM   event 
WHERE (id, created_at) > (@UUID, @Date)  -- ROW value comparison
ORDER  BY id, created_at                 -- ">" matches ASC sort order
LIMIT  3;

See:

SQL syntax term for 'WHERE (col1, col2) < (val1, val2)'
Optimize query with OFFSET on large table


but do I need the filter WHERE ID < ... or it is enough to use filter where created_at asc or desc with limit for pagnigation ?

@locklock123: No filter at all for the first iteration - except constant filters unrelated to paging, of course.

thanks you helped me! if I want to sort by DESC should I make this: (id, created_at) < (@uuid, @date) and order by id desc, created_at desc?

@locklock123 Yes, the WHERE clause and ORDER BY must be in the same direction.

All works perfect, but there is one thing. I use infinite scroll and if I get the last id and want to make key pagningation with the last id and created date then I get duplicate value because the last id is in the previous query and now in the new data. And then the same for the next last id

To void duplication, base keyset pagination ion a unique set of columns. In your case (id, created_at) should be unique. That's all in the links I added. (Obviously, id can be repeated if there are multiple rows per id.)
